# PHP and JavaScript array attachmant

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, function

I have the following problem:

```
onclick=langedit('".$carray2['example']."','".$carray2['id']."')
```

`$carray2['example']` is a string containing `"ABOUT US"` with space, and this is the output in HTML:

```
onclick='langedit('Contact" us','9')="">
```

My PHP code :

```
else {
$cquery2 = mysql_query ("SELECT id,example,".$startlan." FROM language WHERE example = '$word'");
$carray2 = mysql_fetch_array($cquery2);
if($carray2[$startlan] == '') {
if($_SESSION['view'] == 'admin' && isset($_SESSION['siteshow'])){
echo  "<span class='langedit' id='langedit".$carray2['id']."' onclick=langedit('".$carray2['example']."','".$carray2['id']."')><img src='images/sys/edit.png' > </span>";
return $carray2['example'];
}else{
return $carray2['example'];
}
}
```

I don't know what's happening, the `langedit` function does not work because of this.

Comment: You're going to need to add more code.

Comment: Have you tried running that line? It doesn't generate the output you've given. You're going to need to show us more code than that.

Comment: P.S when i edit my DB and insert into here AboutUs instead of About Us it works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cover the `langedit` call on `onclick` with double quotes

```
onclick=\"langedit('".$carray2['example']."','".$carray2['id']."')\"
```

Otherwise if `$carray2['example']` is `About Us`, the `onclick` attribute becomes `onclick=langedit('About` which is an invalid function call.